# How to include spaces as characters in lists

Tags: python

This is my current code:

```
key = input("Enter the key: ")
sent = input("Enter a sentence: ")
print()# for turnin
print()

print("With a key of:",key)
print("Original sentence:",sent)
print()

#split = sent.split()
blank = [ ]
for word in sent:
    for ch in word:
        blank = blank + ch.split()
print(blank)
print()
```

What i have now gives me a list of all the letters in my sentence, but no spaces. If i use this...

```
for word in sent:
    for ch in word:
        print(ch.split())
```

It gives me a list of all characters including the spaces. Is there to get this result and have it equal a variable?

Comment: For what you're asking, do `list(sent)`. But for what you probably actually want, [see @rodrigo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21947895/1446048).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want individual characters of a string, pass it to `list`.

```
>>> list('This is a string.')
['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '.']
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a list of all characters in the sentence, use

```
chars = list(sent)
```

What you're doing is definitely not what you think you're doing.

```
for word in sent:
```

This doesn't loop over the words. This loops over the characters. This:

```
for word in sent.split()
```

would loop over the words.

```
    for ch in word:
```

Since `word` is a character already, this loops over a single character. If it weren't for the fact that characters are represented as length-1 strings, this would throw some kind of error.

Comment: I never think about strings as iterables in this sense. I may use `in` on them, and may iterate on them in list comps (as in my answer), but simply handing them to `list()` is something I've never done, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`sent` is of type string. and when you iterate over a string this way:

```
for word in sent:
```

you get the individual characters, not the words.

Then you iterate over a single char:

```
    for ch in word:
```

and get that very same char (!).

And then with that `split()` call you convert a non-blank character, say `'x'` into a list with itself as element (`['x']`) and a blank characters into the empty list.

You probably want something along the lines of:

```
for word in sent.split():
    ....
```

But if what you want is to build a list of words, no need to iterate, that's exactly what `sent.split()` will get you!

And if what you want is a list of chars, do `list(sent)`.

From `help(str.split)`:

> `split(...)`
>
> `S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings`
>
> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
>       delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>       splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
>       whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
>       removed from the result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but it seems like....

```
blank = [ch for ch in sent]
```

...that's all you need....

Let me give you some sample Ins and Outs and see if that's what you want.

```
IN = "Hello world!"
OUT =>
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```

Is that right?

Comment: @user3330472 the other answers are faster than using a list comp as I do. Use one of them! If you pass a string like `sent` to a list constructor (`list()`), then it returns a list containing each member of the string.

Comment: @user3330472 as an addition, if you're looking to get only ONE copy of everything, e.g. `['H', 'e', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'd', '!']`, use `set(sent)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "This here is a string"

>>> x = list(string) # I think list() is what you are looking for... It's not clear
>>> print x
['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']

>>> print string.split() # default arg is a space
['This', 'here', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```